# How to save the dynamic input from command line to a file in the same format as input using Shell script

Tags: shell-script

I want to save dynamic multiline input from command line to a file in the same format as input.

For Eg:

Code to get the dynamic input:

```
echo "Enter the multi-line message"
message=$(sed '/one.*/q')
echo $message > Finalinput.txt
```

If i give the input message as below,

```
Subject: Subject for the file
Date: Friday, June 11, 2016 @ 02:00am - 06:00am 
Time: 02:00am - 06:00am 


Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Test message Test message Test message Test message Test message

Sincerely,
xxxxx
```

Then the `Finalinput.txt` should also be in the same format like above but instead it is showing as

```
Subject: Subject for the file Date: Friday, June 11, 2016 @ 02:00am - 06:00am Time: 02:00am - 06:00am Test message Test message Test message Test message Test messageTest message Test message Test message Test message Test messageTest message Test message Test message Test message Test messageTest message Test message Test message Test message Test messageTest message Test message Test message Test message Test messageTest message Test message Test message Test message Test message
Sincerely,
xxxxx
```

Because of this problem, sed commands are replacing some wrong pattern. Kindly help me to save the dynamic input from command line to a file in the same format as input using Shell script

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `echo` as it will not do the right thing. You should use double quotes around the variable or the newlines will not be preserved:

```
echo "$message" >Finalinput.txt
```

If you want, you could do it in a number of different ways too, depending on your needs.  The following puts the text into the `message` variable, but also writes it to the file in one go:

```
message="$( sed '/one.*/q' | tee Finalinput.txt )"
```

The `sed` command will get the input from the user and pass it to `tee` which will duplicate it, once to `Finalinput.txt` and once into the `message` variable.

If there isn't a need for keeping the text in a variable at all, then just

```
sed '/one.*/q' >Finalinput.txt
```

will work just as good.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail. It works for me.